# Topological degree mod 2 and polynomial degree

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables

Let $F:(\mathbb{C}^n,0)\to (\mathbb{C}^n,0)$ be a germ of a homeomorphism such that $\|F(x)\|=\|x\|$, for all $x$ sufficiently small and $g:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ a polynomial with $k=$ord$_0 g$. Let $L$ be a complex line (with $0\in L$) and $H=F(L)$ such that there is $r>0$ satisfying 
$$V(g)\cap (H \cup L)\cap \{z\in \mathbb{C}^n; \|z\|\leq r\}=\{0\}.$$ Let $d$ be the topological degree of the map $h:S_r=\{z\in L; \|z\|=r\}\to \mathbb{S}^1$, where $h=\frac{g\circ F}{|g\circ F|}|_{S_r}$.

Is it true that $d=k$ (mod 2)?